# How to implement instantiation of TcpClient, IPEndPoint , IPAddress objects instantiating for both cases IPv4 and IPv6 address when passed As Strings

Tags: c#, sockets, ip-address, tcpclient, tcplistener

For my .NET C# application, we have  modules that are need to communicate via the TCP/IP protocol.

I decided to use Microsoft's System.Net.Sockets API

The modules that are represented by the "TcpListener" class could be either be

-IPv4 address based
-IPv6 address based

The problem is that the modules that use the "TcpClient" class need to instantiate the "TcpClient" in such a way that it is intelligent to take either IPv4 or IPv6 address (that initially gets passed as a string)

To elaborate, the module that uses "TcpClient" class could have a constructor like the following:

```
public ClientModule(string ipV4OrIpV6Address, int portNumber){
………………………
…………..
……….
}
```

When I reviewed Microsoft's documentation ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Net_Sockets_TcpClient__ctor_System_Net_IPEndPoint_ ) , I found the following TcpClient constructor:

> TcpClient(IPEndPoint)
>
> Initializes a new instance of the TcpClient class and binds it to the
>   specified local endpoint.

Furthermore, I tried to search more about instantiating the IPEndPoint class, and I came across ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ipendpoint.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Net_IPEndPoint__ctor_System_Net_IPAddress_System_Int32_ )

Each of the modules will be on different physical computer servers.

How do I go about instantiating the Microsoft's IPAddress object in such a way that it will be intelligent enough to handle both IPv4 and IPv6 address As Strings regardless of which one gets passed as an argument?

Comment: I'd suggest creating a common interface that can be used by the modules, and then abstract away the creation of the underlying infrastructure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`TcpClient(string, int)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Net_Sockets_TcpClient__ctor_System_String_System_Int32_) constructor ultimately winds up calling `IPAddress.TryParse(string)` on the string value you pass in, and it will attempt to apply the result to both an IPv4 and IPv6 socket.

So, you should not have to do anything special. Just pass the IP address to the `TcpClient(string, int)` constructor and let the `TcpClient` class deal with it (well, actually the `Dns` class ultimately is what does the address resolution). There should be no need to do any explicit work to handle IPv6 addresses. Parsing the address yourself is just a waste of code and time.

Comment: "ultimately winds up calling ..." This occurs after a kernel context switch to ring 0 and back. This incurs a performance penalty.  Not to mention the delays and possible security impact (hosts file) of what it may have tried first, since https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/172218/microsoft-tcp-ip-host-name-resolution-order does not specify IP addresses in the order.  "waste of code and time" is relative to whose code and time: Adding IPAddress.TryParse(string IP ,**out IPAddress address**) or IPAddress.Parse( string ipAddress) removes the overhead of the `DNS` resolution.

Comment: @Strom: that's one way to look at it. On the other hand, it means you can accept actual host names in addition to IP addresses, in either format, without any extra user code. The network I/O is slow enough that kernel context switches are irrelevant, and networking code is easy enough to get wrong or overlook useful scenarios, that it's better to just let the framework deal with it when it can.

Comment: Can you tell me when the resolution actually occurs?

Comment: @Strom: all due respect, but...if you have a legitimate conflict of interest with respect to Microsoft's .NET source code, then you have exactly zero business asking anyone else to interpret that source code on your behalf. There is potential conflict regardless of how you learn of the inner-workings of it. Frankly, you probably ought to avoid involving yourself in any discussions regarding the use and behavior of said code, specifically because such discussion may inadvertently expose you to information that would be a conflict of interest.

Comment: @peter-duniho Thx, but let's say I code TcpClient(ipV4OrIpV6AddressAsString) , how would I specify the port number, would the following code work TcpClient(ipV4OrIpV6AddressAsString + " " +portNumberAsString);

Comment: @crazyTech: sorry, my post was a little misleading...the constructor that takes a `string` value also takes the port as a separate parameter. Updated the answer above.

Answer (score 4):

Use [IPAddress.Parse(string ipAddress)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ipaddress.parse?view=netframework-4.8#System_Net_IPAddress_Parse_System_String_) to build the endpoint.

It accepts a string containg either an IPv4 dotted decimal notation or IPv6 Colon separated address string, and returns an `System.Net.IPAddress`.

```
public void ClientModule(string ipV4OrIpV6Address, int portNumber)
{
   IPEndPoint endpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ipV4OrIpV6Address), int port); 
TcpClient client = new TcpClient(endpoint);
// Do something with the client
}
```